# How to create a unique session id (unlike SSPID)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I wonder how to get or create a session id which is unique on a database forever.

The `@SSPID` is not unique. It is reused after someone logs out.

Comment: What do you need it for? GUIDs are the usual method for creating something considered 'unique'

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen How can I get the GUID on login? With a database trigger? The idea is to have a unique ID which can be used for logging various user action.

Comment: you want a persistent ID or changes opon every session ?

Comment: @Squirrel **persistent.** every single session should be identifyable, even after years.

Comment: then how do you identify this login session is same or is a new login session ?

Comment: Maybe you can explain what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: @Squirrel Logging various user action.

Comment: login ID + SPID will be unique at any one time.

Comment: @Squirrel No, a login can get the same SSPID over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Insufficient reputation which is why this is an answer not a comment.

You can use SPID + GETDATE() to get a unique identifiable session even after years.

Comment: But how do I create that? And how do I keep it the same during one sessin? The unique ID needs to be created during login, and then it needs to be the same during the whole session. If I call `GetDate()` again, then it will change of course.

Comment: Create the unique ID only during login. Why call `GETDATE()` again for the same session?

Comment: OK, let's assume I create the ID during login. Then later, I need it in some update trigger. or inaother proceudre. How do I get the same ID now again?

Comment: Alright. Insert this unique ID, session's SPID in a table. This table will have a list of all the unique IDs only until the corresponding session is valid. After the session ends, delete the record.

Answer (score 0):

you can use LOGON trigger to generate a unique id and insert into table. Your App can then retrieve this ID for usage

```
    CREATE TABLE session_audit
    (
        uid     uniqueidentifier not null,
        login_name  varchar(100),
        login_dt    datetime,
        session_id  smallint,
        hostname    nvarchar(128),
        constraint pk_session_audit primary key (uid)
    )

CREATE  TRIGGER session_audit_trigger
ON ALL SERVER FOR LOGON
AS 
BEGIN
    IF  SUSER_SNAME() not in ('sa') -- do not log for sa
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Test.dbo.session_audit (uid, login_name, login_dt, session_id, hostname) 
    SELECT NEWID(), SUSER_SNAME(), GETDATE(), @@SPID, HOST_NAME();
    END
END;
GO
ENABLE TRIGGER session_audit_trigger ON ALL SERVER;
```

Comment: Thank you (cannot vote up, need 15 reps). That goes in the direction I'm looking for.